# MS Access Relationship help needed

Tags: database, ms-access

I have 2 MS Access Tables.

Table 1

id
room-name

Table 2

wall
cupboard
ceiling

Now... table1.room-name has the room names and table2 contains object (many) so each room name contains many objects.

My question is ... How do I set the relationships for this please?

Comment: Note that you need to be a bit clearer on what exactly the relationships are as I think both my and @amelvin's solutions can match what you say depending on how you read the question - and only one of our solutions should match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
[Room]
RoomId    eg 1               2
RoomName  eg bedroom         kitchen


[RoomItem]
RoomItemId eg 1           eg 2       eg 3
RoomId     eg 1           eg 1       eg 2 
ItemName   eg wardrobe    eg bed     eg cooker
```

Where the RoomId links the Room and RoomItem tables.

Comment: Can I have instead: [Room] id, room-name [RoomItem] Id, RoomItemId, ItemName ?

Comment: @Satch3000 Is the Id column in the two tables (in your comment) the id of the room?  If so you can do it that way - as its just a rename of the columns in the answer.

Comment: So.. [RoomItem] RoomItemId = Type: Number , RoomId = Type: Number and ItemName  = Type: Text right?

Comment: @Satch3000 - sounds good, will you be using autonumber for RoomItem.RoomItemId and Room.RoomId ?

Comment: [Room] RoomId already has Autonumber, so on [RoomItem] Table, should I need to use autonumber at all?

Comment: @Satch3000 Use autonumber for the RoomItem.RoomItemId column, use number for RoomItem.RoomId - the RoomItem.RoomId column is a foreign key of the Room.RoomId column

Comment: @Satch3000 - note that this solution means that a roomitem could be in several rooms whilst mine say that a roomitem can only be in one room (it helps to name the tables as the entity you are modelling - not just tablennn)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in table 2 tells you what room things are in so you need to add a foreign key of the room to the primary key of table 1. In this case either column of table1 could be its primary key - I would use  room- name and drop the id.

So table2 needs altering so that room-name is in it and the draw the connection from table1 to table2.